# "too many parameters" on perfectly fine function

Tags: methods, types, rust, traits

I have code similar to this:

```
pub trait WorldImpl {
    fn new(size: (usize, usize), seed: u32) -> World;
    fn three() -> bool;
    fn other() -> bool;
    fn non_self_methods() -> bool;
}
pub type World = Vec<Vec<UnitOfSpace>>;
// I'm doing this because I want a SPECIAL version of Vec<Vec<UnitOfSpace>>, so I can treat it like a struct but have it be a normal type underneath.
impl WorldImpl for World {
    fn new(size: (usize, usize), seed: u32) -> World {
    // Code
        vec![/* vector stuff */]
    }
    // Implement other three methods
}
let w = World::new((120, 120), /* seed from UNIX_EPOCH stuff */);
```

And I get this error, which is clearly wrong:

```
error[E0061]: this function takes 0 parameters but 2 parameters were supplied
  --> src/main.rs:28:28
   |
28 |     let world = World::new((120 as usize, 120 as usize),
   |                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected 0 parameters
```

I'm thinking two things:

1. This is not idiomatic and Rust was never meant to be used this way. In this case, I need to know how to really do this.
2. It's a stupid error that I'm missing.

When I try similar code to the above on the playground, it works just fine, no errors. I have not found any information on any errors like this anywhere else, so I'll not be surprised to find out I'm just using the language wrong. I have no particular attachment to any of my code, so please tell me what the idiom is for this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are trying to do doesn't quite make sense. You have made `World` a type alias for `Vec<Vec<UnitOfSpace>>`, so they are completely interchangeable - the implementations you add for one will apply to the other and vice versa.

If you want to treat this type differently then wrap it in a newtype:

```
struct World(Vec<Vec<UnitOfSpace>>);
```

This is now a distinct type from `Vec<Vec<UnitOfSpace>>`, but with zero runtime overhead.

Your actual error is because you have added a method called `new` to `World` as part of its implementation of `WorldImpl`, but `World` is a `Vec` which already has a `new` method (with zero args!).

Comment: Oh. Ah. *facepalm*

Answer (score 1):

Your type `World` is an alias for `Vec<Vec<UnitOfSpace>>`. `Vec<T>` provides an inherent associated function called [`new`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.new) that takes no parameters. The compiler prefers selecting inherent associated functions to associated functions defined in traits, thus it selects the inherent `new` with no parameters instead of your own `new` that takes 2 parameters.

Here are a few options to solve this:

1. Invoke the trait's associated function explicitly:

   ```
   let w = <World as WorldImpl>::new((120, 120), /* seed from UNIX_EPOCH stuff */);
   ```
2. Make `World` a newtype (`struct World(Vec<Vec<UnitOfSpace>>);`), which will let you define inherent associated functions (but then `Vec`'s inherent methods won't be available on `World`).
3. Rename `WorldImpl::new` to a name that is not used by an inherent associated function on `Vec`.

Comment: They could also change the name of `WorldImpl::new`.

Comment: Not the OP, but do you have a link that might elaborate on why Rust prefers the inherent fn instead of erroring due to duplicates in cases like this?

Comment: @loganfsmyth: No link, but from what I recall the reasoning is that if it *didn't* do this, it would make introducing new standard traits (or adding methods to existing traits) effectively impossible.  New traits and/or methods could shadow inherent methods on people's types, breaking existing code.